# Foundation 5: sticky Nav for Mobile

Tags: html, zurb-foundation, nav

I have a simple one page site. Im using the "top-bar" wrapped in a "fixed" div, which works fine on every size but mobile. On mobile the nav is in fact fixed until the menu icon is clicked/tapped. then it opens the menu at the top of the page and nav is no longer fixed.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="fixed">
  <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
    <ul class="title-area">

      <!-- Title Area -->
          <li class="name">
            <h1>
              <a href="#">Page Title</a>
            </h1>
          </li>
          <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>

    <section class="top-bar-section">

      <!-- Right Nav Section -->
      <ul class="right">
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#process">Process</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#books">Bookshelf</a></li>
         <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#brands">Brands</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#want">Looking for</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </nav>
 </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please do add css or it would be great if you add a fiddle.

Comment: You can see the site live here: http://www.basiegel.com/ I have other issues too but this one first.

Comment: dude its working fine for me... which browser & version you are using?

Comment: Im using Chrome 32, Firefox 26, IE 11, Opera 19. It still looks like,  once the menu icon is clicked/tapped it jumps to the top of the page. How do I stop this from happening. - thanks